# Why is the isChecked() method not declared?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, bluej, jradiobutton

I try to use the `isChecked()` method to identify whether a radio button is selected or not, and I get an error saying 'cannot find symbol'; I have imported `java.awt.event.*` so it's not that! It's probably something stupid but I'm really stuck!

```
if (beginner.isChecked()) 
{
   difficultyMark = 1;
}
else if (normal.isChecked()) 
{
   difficultyMark = 2;
} else {
   difficultyMark = 3;
}
```

Comment: Because `JRadioButton` doesn't have a `isChecked` method.  If you consulted the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html), and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) tutorial, you would find that it uses [`isSelected`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected()) instead

Comment: I did look at JavaDocs but I'm very new to programming and I didn't have a clue what I was looking at, what section of the JavaDocs do you look at to find this?

Comment: aha, yes thank you that's sorted it, In future I will try and look more but I find the JavaDocs very baffling!

Comment: Spend some time with the tutorials as well, that's why they are there.

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate your help, I will definitely look at some tutorials